# Update a column(TEXT) with HTML text (contains ' and ")

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

The table (myTAB) has a column named HTML format in TEXT NOT NULL;

The PRIMARY column and other columns are already there and correct, only I need to fill the HTML column, thus I tried:

```
... 
TB_NAME = 'myTAB'
open_html = open(f.html, 'r')
content = open_html.read()
...
sql =  "UPDATE "+ TB_NAME + " SET HTML = " + content
cursor.execute(sql)
```

I always got:

> error 1064(42000): error in SQL syntax...

I guess it may relate to the html file contains already the signs of ' or ";

Also I have tried:

```
sql = ' UPDTAE %s SET HTML = %s '
val = (TB_NAME, content)
cursor.execute(sql,val)
```

same error, also tried using str(content) , no success.

---

BTW: if the table is empty to insert, no problem! e.g.:

```
sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO ' + TB_NAME + '(c0,c1,c2,HTML) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
val.append(content)
cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: you should use ORMs like `sqlalchemy`

Comment: Isn't this prone to [SQL Injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: lshan: thanks but I prefer stay. @Uwe: :-) I don't understand you mean, first save/drop then insert in total?

Comment: @UweKeim, tried just now, it works, but ... feels awkward! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried:

```
sql =  "UPDATE "+ TB_NAME + " SET HTML = " + content
cursor.execute(sql)`
```

First of all, you are missing single quotes around the content. But since your content might contain embedded single quote, this still would not work. Also, this expression exposes you to SQL injection.

---

You also tried:

```
sql = ' UPDATE %s SET HTML = %s '
val = (TB_NAME, content)
cursor.execute(sql,val)
```

You are properly passing the html content as a parameter. But this doesn't work since *table names* cannot be parameterized.

---

I would recommend contatenating the table name and passing the html content as a parameter:

```
sql = ' UPDATE ' + TB_NAME + ' SET HTML = %s '
val = [content]   # instead of (content)
cursor.execute(sql,val)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Yet val = (content) not wroking, but val = [content] it will take :-) would you explain?

Comment: Thanks again! In fact, even `content = None` I can use `val=[content]` for the the HTML entry as NULL, so [] is superior to ()